# react-dropzone should only accept .jpg and .jpeg but none of the other JPG variants

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm using react-dropzone to drop the following image file extensions.

```
   accept: {
   'image/*': ['.gif', '.jpeg', '.pjpeg', '.png', '.bmp', '.svg+xml']
   },
   noClick: true,
   noKeyboard: true,
   multiple: true,
   onDrop: onDrop(files),
 })
```

But still, I can select JFIF of JPG variants. How can I fix this?

I tried using multiple MIME types matching their extension as well. it doesn't work for me.

```
    accept: {
      'image/png': ['.png'],
      'image/jpeg': ['.jpeg'],
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```js
accept: {
   'image/jpeg': [],
   'image/png': [],
   'image/webp': [],
   'image/heic': [],
   'image/jfif': [],
},
```

These are the only extensions that I can select.